# Navigation bar disappears in a push segue loop

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue, navigationbar

I am using Storyboards

I have 3 view controllers (A, B, and C) that I want to have arranged, so that each one segues into another; like a directed triangle.

A is reached from another controller (lets call it A'), it segues into B, and that segues into C; and I want C to segue back to A.

A' is embedded into a navigation controller, and so A,B and C have a bar as well. However when I make a segue from C to A, that bar disappears from all three view controllers.

How do I prevent this from happening? Should I add a UINavigationBar to each of the 3 controllers?

Comment: You only need to add a navigation controller on the top of your three view and push views. Add your code

Comment: Actually, when I run the simulator with my intentional set up, the navigation bar is visible in the running program. Not sure why I can't see it in the storyboard. The issue I have now is that I want to be able to add buttons, but I can't if I can't see the bar in the storyboard. It is probably one of those little bugs that came in the Xcode 5 update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured this solution a while back, completely forgot about this question. In the storyboard, select the view controllers you are having issues with and, in the Attributes Inspector, change the Top Bar setting to a specific type of navigation bar rather than Inferred. This keeps the bar visible at all times for the corresponding UIViewController

I assume, of course, you have a segue path that contains a UINavigationController somewhere before your respective controllers. I'm not sure if it would work without one.

Comment: Are talking about Simulated Metrics part of Attributes Inspector? If so - are you sure that they can affect real app?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too. Things are good in simulator but they are not displayed correctly in storyboard. 
You can use following code in the action of bar button to do it:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController: [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```